Backend gets stuck in deployment
I have a project that gets deployed on an EC2 instance automatically via GitHub Actions. But after some recent changes to the code, the deployment takes too long and often gets stuck somewhere in between the deployment process. Mainly it gets stuck at tsc -p . and other times anywhere random. I have the logs of GitHub Actions here. There is nothing wrong with the compilation in local environment.

How to debug this or what are the steps I can follow to fix this?
I tried to fix the TypeScript compilation as it was producing an error. It got resolved for once and the code was deployed with no issues, but then again it started getting stuck while producing no errors whatsoever.
There is no problem with the EC2 instance as well. Can it be the case that my Node version is old (16) which is producing problems?
This is the workflow:
name: Node.js CI Backend

on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]
    paths: ["backend/**"]

jobs:
  deploy_backend:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Authentication with ec2
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.6
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.BACKEND_HOSTNAME}}
          username: ${{ secrets.BACKEND_USER}}
          key: ${{ secrets.BACKEND_SSH_KEY }}
          port: ${{ secrets.BACKEND_PORT }}
          script: |
            cd /home/webapps/mvp/backend
            sudo git reset --hard
            sudo git pull https://github.com/abcd/mvp
            ./deploy.sh

This is deploy.sh:
dir="/home/webapps/mvp/backend"

echo "${cyan}Generating Backup${clear}"
ts-node ${dir}/scripts/backupDB.ts
echo "${green}Backup creation Sucessful ! ${clear}"
cd ${dir}
echo "${cyan}Getting ready to deploy${clear}"
echo "${cyan}Installing and Updating Dependencies${clear} "
sudo npm i
echo "${green}Done:${clear} Installing and Updating Dependencies"
echo "${cyan}Now Genrating Prisma Client${clear} "
npx prisma generate
echo "${green}Done:${clear} Genrating Prisma Client"
echo "${cyan}Migrating Schema${clear} "
npx prisma migrate deploy
echo "${green}Done:${clear} Migrating Schema"
echo "${cyan}Manifesting build directory${clear} "
npm run build
echo "${green}Done:${clear} build directory manifested"
pm2 reload "npm start" --update-env
echo "${green}All Done${clear} ✨"
echo "${green}Success:${clear} Server is now live "


As shown in the above screenshot, the deployment gets stuck. Sometimes it gets stuck on the deploy.sh script and it is only a basic deployment script. Not anything fancy.

without seeing deploy.sh it's a bit hard to help you

Shared @JaromandaX

I upgraded my ec2 instance from micro to medium and I can merge the code. I think the CPU utilization went off the charts whenever I merged my code and that made the instance freeze. Hope it keeps working ! Will update if anything goes wrong.
